# Using CAMEL in synchronization with PostgreSQL

Tags: web-services, spring, apache-camel

I have Spring WS which is creating a record in database after SOAP request, and then it should wait till response appear.
 (i have two tables in DB - requestTable -record is created when request to WS came, and responseTable - records are created by independent source). 
 
 When Method detect that record linked with request appear in responseTable, WS send proper response.
Problem lies in synchronization because i can't ( actually i can but i don't want to) create a wait for n seconds thread, i want to make it using CAMEL, I read somewhere that CAMEL implements method that is proper for this kind of situation abut now I can't find it again. 
And i have a question for You: Do you have a hint how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post the way i did this.
Solution with using JMS channel between WS and Database what is described here works great:
[Transparent Asynchronous Remoting via JMS](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2011/03/transparent-asynchronous-remoting-via.html)